# Azure Cosmos DB REST API suddenly not returning all results

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I've got a React Native app that's using Azure Cosmos DB that has stopped working suddenly. It's been working for months without problem and then when the scale was changed on the Cosmos DB portal it's no longer working.

If I query in the Document Explorer in Azure Cosmos DB portal it returns 38 documents but if I query using Postman then I only get 24 documents.  The odd thing is that it is returning every other document.

I'm absolutely stumped.  Any ideas?

I've checked the REST API version is the latest and I've rerun the REST API call but I get the same result every time.   It's very confusing.

Comment: Are you consuming the continuation token header?

Comment: Would there be a continuation token for only 38 documents?

Comment: Sure, it can. Are you not getting the continuation token header in the response?

Comment: Are you doing a GROUP BY operaiton?

Comment: No I am not doing a GROUP BY.  This is on every operation.

Answer (score 0):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/pagination

> In Azure Cosmos DB's REST API, you can manage continuation tokens with the x-ms-continuation header. As with querying with the .NET or Java SDK, if the x-ms-continuation response header is not empty, it means the query has additional results.

Make sure you are consuming the `x-ms-continuation` header to continue the query execution.

Query can yield due to multiple reasons:

> In addition, there are other reasons that the query engine might need to split query results into multiple pages. These include:

- The container was throttled and there weren't available RUs to return more  query results.
- The query execution's response was too large
- The query execution's time was too long
- It was more efficient for the query engine to return results in additional executions